# 2 загрузчика на разных SSD

Tags: linux, windows, ос, dual-boot

Имеется ноутбук с 2-я слотами под SSD, собственно один под Windows, а на второй я хочу поставить Linux.    Возможно ли провернуть следующее:

1. Поставить второй SSD и снять первый, на котором Windows.
2. На чистую установить Linux на новый SSD.
3. Вставить оригинальный SSD на место.

Итого мы имеем 2 совершенно разных загрузчика на 2-х разных SSD. Для переключения между системами в биос менять приоритет загрузки (SSD 1 и SSD 2). Сработает ли это или имеются подводные камни?
Ноутбук Xiaomi mi notebook air 13.3

Comment: Зачем так усложнять? Grub один отлично справится с загрузкой Windows и Linux. И удобней будет, то есть можно будет выбрать какую ос грузить вручную и выставить какая будет грузится сразу.

Comment: @excellproj проблема в том, что Linux скорее эксперимент над собой, так что если не зайдет хочу без следа снести и забыть как страшный сон) Прошлая такая попытка потерпела фиаско и я мучился с чисткой загрузчика, так как Винду терять не хотел, короче не очень было...

Comment: Так в этом тоже нет проблемы. Восстановить загрузчик винды либо оставить загрузчик Grub и Linux снести.

Comment: @excellproj ну не знаю... Как по мне из винды форматнуть второй ссд проще) а эта схема не сработает?

Comment: В теории должно сработать. В процессе запуска bios, если он поддерживает, выбирать диск с которого грузится через F8. Какой дистрибутив выбрали?

Comment: @excellproj спасибо! Пока остановился на Elementary OS из-за того что под капотом Ubuntu, но при этом приятный GUI. Unity не очень нравится

Comment: Ничем не отличается от варианта SSD + USB флешка. Не только теоретически, но и практически так работает. UEFI умеет выбирать загрузчик, если надо очень (снова же, в случае с UEFI вообще для Linux *отдельный* загрузчик не нужен)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш вариант сработает однозначно!
и все будет так как вы задумали.
Но, для понимания и простоты реализации:

- чтобы не вытаскивать/втаскивать диски, у вас(для примера) на ssd1/sda1 стоит винда и он включен в bios как загрузочный.
  Вставляем второй диск ssd2/sda2(чистый), переключаем в bios его как загрузочный.

  - устанавливаем Linux, и при установке grub2, указываем, что его установить именно на sda2/ssd2. При этом он подхватит винду не затерев!!! загрузчик винды на sda1/ssd1, и при следующих загрузках вы легко сможете выбирать что загружать!
  - если вам не понравился Linux, вы просто в bios потом переключаете загрузку на первый ssd1 с рабочим win загрузчиком, и запускаете стандарто винду, а со вторым диском делаете что хотите) - хоть форматируете, хоть в другой комп вставляете.

Профит)

Comment: Супер! Огромное спасибо за ваш ответ)